# Unable to extract zip file on android

Tags: android, kotlin, zip, retrofit

I'm  trying to download and extract a zip file from an endpoint using retrofit and kotlin in android. The zip file is downloaded but seem unable to extract, I have tried to download the zip file via postman and do a manual extraction and it worked, however it is not extracting the file in the android code for some reason, I have tried different file read and write methods but the downloaded zip file cannot be extracted neither by code nor file explorer.

The code was working initially but stopped working, I recently upgraded my compile sdk version and target sdk version from 33 to 34. I'm trying to download the zip and subsequently extract it in my internal app directory.

Below shows the download and extraction code:

```
// The download method
suspend fun downloadAndSaveImages(info: ExamContentInfo, token: String): Pair<String?, ResultState<ResponseBody>> {
    return try {
        val response = withContext(dispatcherProvider.io) {
            remoteDataSourceImpl.downloadPQImages(info.appSlug, info.freeContentMedia, info.contentVersionMedia, token)
        }

        val imagesLogDocId = response.headers()[CONTENT_LOG_DOC_ID]

        if (response.code() != 200) {
            val body = response.errorBody()
            val gson = Gson()
            val type = object : TypeToken<ApiErrorResponse>() {}.type
            val errorResponse: ApiErrorResponse? = gson.fromJson(body?.charStream(), type)

            val errorMessage = errorResponse?.message ?: "An Error Occurred"
            return Pair(imagesLogDocId, ResultState.Error(errorMessage))
        }

        return response.body()?.let { body ->
            body.savePQImages5(context)
            return Pair(imagesLogDocId, ResultState.Success(body))
        } ?: Pair(imagesLogDocId, ResultState.Error("No content"))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        val imagesLogDocId = null
        when (e) {
            is IOException -> Pair(imagesLogDocId, ResultState.Error("Network Error"))
            else -> Pair(imagesLogDocId, ResultState.Error("An Error Occurred"))
        }
    }
}


// The retrofit method, I have tried it with and without the @Streaming annotation 

//    @Streaming
@GET("/api/v1/content/pq-images")
suspend fun downloadPQImages(
    @Query("app_slug") appSlug: String,
    @Query("free") freeContent: Boolean,
    @Query("content_version") contentVersion: String,
    @Header("Authorization") token: String
): Response<ResponseBody>



// The different methods I have used for saving the zip file

fun ResponseBody.savePQImages(context: Context) {
    val fileDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
    val zipFile = File(fileDirectory, FetchFetchExamContentRepositoryImpl.ZIP_FILE_NAME)
    byteStream().use { inputStream->
        zipFile.outputStream().use { outputStream->
            inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        }
    }
}

fun ResponseBody.savePQImages2(context: Context) {
    val fileDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
    val zipFile = File(fileDirectory, FetchFetchExamContentRepositoryImpl.ZIP_FILE_NAME_2)
    val input = byteStream()
    val fos = FileOutputStream(zipFile.absolutePath)
    fos.use { output ->
        val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // or other buffer size
        var read: Int
        while (input.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read)
        }
        output.flush()
    }
}

fun ResponseBody.savePQImages3(context: Context) {
    val fileDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
    val zipFile = File(fileDirectory, FetchFetchExamContentRepositoryImpl.ZIP_FILE_NAME_3)

    source().run {
        zipFile.sink().buffer().use { it.writeAll(this) }
        val crc32 = CRC32()
        zipFile.inputStream().use {
            crc32.update(it.readBytes())
        }
    }

    val outputFolderPath = zipFile.parent
    val inputStream = FileInputStream(zipFile)
    var filename: String
    val zis = ZipInputStream(BufferedInputStream(inputStream))
    var ze: ZipEntry?
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var count: Int

    zis.use {
        while (zis.nextEntry.also { ze = it } != null) {
            filename = ze?.name ?: break
            // Need to create directories if not exists, or
            // it will generate an Exception...
            if (ze?.isDirectory ?: break) {
                val fmd = File("$outputFolderPath/$filename")
                fmd.mkdirs()
                continue
            }
            FileOutputStream("$outputFolderPath/$filename").use{
                while (zis.read(buffer).also { bytes -> count = bytes } != -1) {
                    it.write(buffer, 0, count)
                }
            }
            zis.closeEntry()
        }
    }
}

fun ResponseBody.savePQImages4(context: Context) {
    val fileDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
//    val fileToZip = File(fileDirectory, FetchFetchExamContentRepositoryImpl.ZIP_FILE_NAME_4)
    val fileToZip = File(fileDirectory, "file.zip")

    fileToZip.outputStream().use {
        byteStream().copyTo(it)
    }

    val bufferSize = 8192
    val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
    val zipInputStream = ZipInputStream(fileToZip.inputStream())
    var entry: ZipEntry? = zipInputStream.nextEntry
    while (entry != null) {
        val newFile = File(fileDirectory, entry.name)
        if (entry.isDirectory) {
            newFile.mkdirs()
        } else {
            val output = FileOutputStream(newFile)
            val bufferedOutput = BufferedOutputStream(output)
            var count: Int = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)

            while (count != -1) {
                bufferedOutput.write(buffer, 0, count)
                count = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
            }

            bufferedOutput.close()
            output.close()
        }

        zipInputStream.closeEntry()
        entry = zipInputStream.nextEntry
    }
    zipInputStream.close()
}

fun ResponseBody.savePQImages5(context: Context) {
    val downloadedFile = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "pq_images.zip")

    val inputStream = byteStream()
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(downloadedFile)
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
    while (bytesRead != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
    }
    outputStream.close()
    inputStream.close()
}
```

Also below shows the retrofit version used:

```
def retrofitVersion = "2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'
```